# Uniform Convergence for $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{x^{n}}{100+x^{2n}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, uniform-convergence, solution-verification, sequence-of-function

Prove that $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{x^{
n}}{100+x^{2n}}}$$  converges uniformly for $x \in [2,\infty)$?

I tried to prove it by applying *Weierstrass M-test*, where the $M_n$ that I found to be larger or equal to the sum above would  be $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{1}{nx}}$$ but I am not sure if it is an appropriate sum to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0 <\frac {x^{n}} {100+x^{2n}} \leq \frac {x^{n}} {x^{2n}} =\frac 1 {x^{n}} \leq \frac 1 {2^{n}}$ and $\sum \frac 1 {2^{n}}<\infty$.

Comment: Thank you! This is a lot more concrete and efficient.